# Use placeholder to delete rows code in mysql with python mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql-python

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(hostip, username, password, dbname)
cur = conn.cursor()
tablename = raw_input("Choose your table name: ")
if tablename:
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s" % tablename)
rows = cur.fetchall()

desc = cur.description
fields = [j[0] for j in desc]

for row in rows:
    for kword in dust:
        for fs in fields:
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s LIKE '%%s%'" % (tablename, fs, kword))

conn.close()
```

#

Like the simple code, i want to pass the params use %% PlaceHolder in mysqldb, but it doesn't worked, can somehelp me with that sentence? '%%s%'  , first and last '%' is sql syntax that  use 'like'
THANKS VERY MUCH !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of format string using %s and {} show example as below:

```
print "key:%(key)s value:%(value)s" % {"key":"key1","value":"value1"}
print "{{keep me}} key:{key} value:{value}".format(**{"key":"key1","value":"value1"})
```

To solve your problem:

```
>>> "SELECT * FROM {tablename} WHERE {field} LIKE '%{keyword}%'".format(**{"tablename":"UserTable","field":"NameField","keyword":"Wuliang"})
"SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE NameField LIKE '%Wuliang%'"
```